# I need to create a loop that prints a graph where each number in the list is shown by a number of characters. Here is an example:

Tags: list, loops

numbers = [1,2,3,4]

results in

1:    i

2:    ii

3:    iii

4:    iiii

This is my code so far and I'm not sure where to go.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4]

c = 0

for i in numbers:

    count += 1

print(len(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 'i' you can put any character you like enclosed in single inverted commas.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4]
output = []
for number in numbers:
    output.append(number*'i')

print(output)
```